# SQL - explanation on PIVOT behavior

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

For the cost column values from a table course, try to pivot into a table of how many times a cost values happens, e.g $1095 happens 3 times.

```
      1095       1195       1595       NULL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3         25          1          1
```

#### Cost values

```
select cost from course
order by cost;

COST
----------
1095
1095
1095
1195
...
1195
1595
NULL
```

This works.

```
WITH counter AS (
    SELECT 
        cost
    FROM course    
)
select * from counter
pivot (
    count(*)
    for (cost)
    in (1095, 1195, 1595, NULL)
);

      1095       1195       1595       NULL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3         25          1          1
```

This does not.

```
select cost from course
pivot (
    count(*)
    for (cost)
    in (1095, 1195, 1595, NULL)
);

ORA-00904: "COST": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 178 Column: 8
```

## Question

It seems to me both selecting `cost` and doing `count(*)` but the former worked but the latter did not. Please help understand why.

Comment: Because after pivoting all your costs are allocated to the columns with cost amount and there's no `cost` column anymore. You can observe it with `select *`, it shows all the columns you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `select cost from course` doesn't work

  ```
  SQL> select cost from course
    2  pivot (
    3      count(*)
    4      for (cost)
    5      in (1095, 1195, 1595, NULL)
    6  );
  select cost from course
         *
  ERROR at line 1:
  ORA-00904: "COST": invalid identifier
  ```

  See the asterisk? Points to error cause.
- `select *    from course` works:

  ```
  SQL> select * from course
    2  pivot (
    3      count(*)
    4      for (cost)
    5      in (1095, 1195, 1595, NULL)
    6  );

        1095       1195       1595       NULL
  ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
           2          1          1          0
  ```

Reason? That's the syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM                  --> here; there's no "COLUMN1" or "<column list>" but "*"
(
  SELECT column1, column2
  FROM tables
  WHERE conditions
)
PIVOT 
(
  aggregate_function(column2)
  FOR column2
  IN ( expr1, expr2, ... expr_n) | subquery
)
ORDER BY expression [ ASC | DESC ];
```